# update binding dependency property

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a custom user control that I had to extend to add a couple of new elements to. In this control I have the couple of properties already like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CountProperty ", typeof(int), typeof(SomeThirdPartyControl), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public int Count
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CountProperty ); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CountProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

And added the couple of items like this

```
var textBlockFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
            textBlockFactory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(Count)));
```

I also have an update method that just basically does something like:

```
Count = items.Count;
```

When the count gets updated I expect that the UI is updated. However, the value in `textBlockFactory`  never seems to get updated.

How would one go about making sure that FrameworkElement value is updated when the dependency property is changed.

Comment: *" The binding never seems to get updated"* - which binding? *"whenever that value gets updated"* - where it gets updated? Can you add both points to the question please (complete classes, complete methods, etc.)?

Comment: try if this works: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)

Comment: Eventually you can use PropertyChangedCallback to do something when the DependencyProperty is updated. Please clarify your question further. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: I can use the propertychangedCallback but in that callback method how do I access the frameworkelement value to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your DependencyProperty to bind TwoWay by default like @Arie said:

something like this:

```
        public int Count
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(CountProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CountProperty , value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CountProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Count" , typeof(int) , 
                typeof(SomeThirdPartyControl) ,
                  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0 ,
                       FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```